# jquery to bind knockout data-bind

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

just started looking into knockout.js library. I'm just curious to know if it is possible to have all the knockout data-bind expression handled by jQuery rather than inline in the html markup.

what i am trying to do is to have a clean markup and have all the javascript related stuff handled by the jQuery.

Not sure if it make sense to do it but just wanna see if it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign the `data-bind` attributes through jQuery or other means, as long as you do it prior to calling `ko.applyBindings` on those elements.

Many unobtrusive techniques these days do involve using attributes like `data-something`, so using the `data-bind` attribute does follow that pattern.  I suppose though at times the line is blurred when the content of the `data-bind` contains anonymous functions.